# Get part of field not by start/length

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to omit part of a string/field returned by a query. For example, for a string like `999-43875435`, I'd like to get the `43875435` part of it. But I wouldn't like to get it like `SUBSTRING(field, 5, LEN(field)))`. I would like to *subtract* the part I want to omit, and have it return the rest of the string, something like `OMIT(field, '999-', <something that would denote I want it to match the pattern at the beginning of the string>)`. Is there such a function like the one I describe?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a few examples of your original strings and the results you want, so we can understand your problem a little better.

Answer (score 2):

Here are som examples that I think you could do:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(field, CHARINDEX('-', field) + 1, LEN(field))
  , RIGHT(field, LEN(field) - (CHARINDEX('999-', field) + LEN('999-') - 1))
  , REPLACE(field, '999-', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to omit the first 3 characters on all phone numbers, you can replace them with asterisks using a built-in functions like `CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('***', SUBSTRING(phone, 4, 7)) AS Phone 
FROM 
    table;`
```

Result would look like this:

| Phone |
| --- |
| ***4587513 |
| ***3215196 |
| ***4163215 |
| ***3213545 |
| ***4873213 |
| ***7321684 |
| ***4684324 |
| ... |